# pivot table contains additional NULL rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following Sample SQL data week wise.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ('[tempdb].[dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns] (
     [CourseWeek] [int] NULL
    ,[QuestionID] [int] NULL
    ,[QuestionGroupID] [int] NULL
    ,[QuestionType] [varchar](100) NULL
    ,[Question] [varchar](1000) NULL
    ,[Text] [varchar](1000) NULL
    ,[Value] [int] NULL
    ,[IsScore] [bit] NULL
    ,[AnswerScoreOrChoice] [int] NULL
    )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1083,1,'Label','Assess',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1084,1,'DropDown','Do you have any concerns?','No',2,1,NULL
INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1084,1,'DropDown','Do you have any concerns?','Not Applicable',-1,1,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1084,1,'DropDown','Do you have any concerns?','Yes',1,1,1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1085,1,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','Accuracy Of Scoring and Feedback',4,0,4

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1085,1,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','All',1,0,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1085,1,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','Course Access',2,0,2

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1085,1,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','Timely Submission',3,0,3

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1086,2,'Label','Coach',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1087,2,'DropDown','Do you have any concerns?','No',2,1,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1087,2,'DropDown','Do you have any concerns?','Not Applicable',-1,1,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1087,2,'DropDown','Do you have any concerns?','Yes',1,1,1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1088,2,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','All',1,0,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1088,2,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','Communication',3,0,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1088,2,'DropDown','Area Of Concern','Rubric Misuse',2,0,NULL

INSERT INTO [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns]
SELECT 1,1089,3,'Label','Engage',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Trying pivot to generate below expected dataset data but i am not getting expected results.

```
    DECLARE @ExpectedResult TABLE (CourseWeek int,  [Area Lable] varchar(100), [Concerns DDL] varchar(50), [Area DDL] varchar(500))
INSERT INTO @ExpectedResult VALUES (1 ,'Assess','Yes','Accuracy Of Scoring and Feedback,Course Access,Timely Submission')
INSERT INTO @ExpectedResult VALUES (1 ,'Coach','Yes',NULL)
INSERT INTO @ExpectedResult VALUES (1 ,'Engage',NULL,NULL)

SELECT * FROM @ExpectedResult
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcxDD.jpg)

I am trying to achieve similar results as highlighted in the image/@ExpectedResult table data. But I am getting additional NULL rows. Please find the updated Pivot query below, after removing [QuestionID] partially solved my issue but still I am getting Null values.

```
    SELECT [CourseWeek]
    ,[Area Reviewed]
    ,[Concerns DDL]
    ,[Area]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [CourseWeek],
        CASE 
            WHEN [QuestionGroupID] = 1
                THEN 'Assess'
            WHEN [QuestionGroupID] = 2
                THEN 'Coach'
            WHEN [QuestionGroupID] = 3
                THEN 'Engage'
            WHEN [QuestionGroupID] = 4
                THEN 'Support'
            END [Area Reviewed],
        'Concerns DDL' AS [ConQuestionType],
        'Area' AS [AreaQuestionType],
        CASE 
            WHEN [AnswerScoreOrChoice] = 1
                AND [Question] = 'Do you have any concerns?'
                THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN [AnswerScoreOrChoice] > 1
                AND [Question] = 'Do you have any concerns?'
                THEN 'No'
            END [Concerns (Yes/No)],
        AreaOfConcerns = (
            STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + DS2.[Text]
                    FROM [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns] DS2
                    WHERE DS2.[QuestionID] = DS1.[QuestionID]
                        AND DS2.[QuestionType] = DS1.[QuestionType]
                        AND DS2.[CourseWeek] = DS1.[CourseWeek]
                        AND DS2.[Question] = 'Area Of Concern'
                        AND DS2.[Text] <> 'All'
                    FOR XML PATH(''),
                        TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
            )
    FROM [dbo].[##GetSummaryColtSpotQusAns] DS1
    WHERE (
            [AnswerScoreOrChoice] IS NOT NULL
            OR [QuestionType] = 'Label'
            )

    ) AS SRC
PIVOT(MAX([Concerns (Yes/No)]) FOR [ConQuestionType] IN ([Concerns DDL])) AS DES1
PIVOT(MAX(AreaOfConcerns) FOR [AreaQuestionType] IN ([Area])) AS DES2
```

Comment: Consumable Sample data and expected results will greatly help us here. Images don't help us help you, as we can't use them.

Comment: I have updated sample data.

Comment: Hey @sathishkumar.  For sample source data, making it consumable is important.  So thanks for adding it.  However, I think it's inaccurate.  And I would use the values syntax to save you a bunch of lines.  Also, you don't need to make the expected results consumable.  In fact, in my experience an image or carefully structured text results are better for output.  In the end though I think I see your issue and I gave an answer below.

Comment: I have updated my pivot query now. Still I am getting NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that QuestionID in your subquery is acting as a key field, meaning your pivot will pivot 'around' that field along with LabelQuetionType and so on.  And because it will give a distinct value for each row, your pivot will have a lot of null values.

Get rid of QuestionId in your subquery and you will see it will pivot as you desire (though I think your sample data is not accurate as of this writing).

Comment: Partially solved the issue but not completely. Still I am getting null values. I have updated my  pivot query in question.